# Scala,Cats, usage of `ap`

Tags: scala, functional-programming, functor, scala-cats, applicative

I am going trough the https://www.scala-exercises.org/ for Cats. I guess that I understand what does `Apply.ap`. But I cannot see any usage of that.

What is the difference between:

```
Apply[Option].map(Some(1))(intToString)
```

and

```
Apply[Option].ap(Some(intToString))(Some(1))
```

Can someone explain a bit more or point me to more explanations ?

Comment: Being honest, I have never used `ap` directly. Rather, I have used it implicitly using things like `tupled`, `mapN` and `traverse`.

Comment: Thanks this was my understanding "not in user code". Luis, there is also `apN` like `mapN`, but I guess the answer is the same.

Comment: `Apply` is a specialized type class of `Applicative`, which is also a Functor. Applicative provides `ap` operation. It’s very similar to Functor’s map but the function in the argument is already in `F[_]` domain. In a lot of cases like Monoids they can be used interchangeably with a few exceptions.

Comment: In FP `ap` is more often used as a composition with `map` of the shape `ap(map)`, which is better known as `liftA2`. Please note that `ap` is a very fundamental operation and you should know when to use it instead of `flatMap`.

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference between

```
Apply[Option].map(Some(1))(intToString)
```

and

```
Apply[Option].ap(Some(intToString))(Some(1))
```

Both are `Some("1")`.

But there is a big difference between `map` and `ap`.

`map` comes from the type class `Functor` and has a signature

```
def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]
```

`ap` comes from the type class `Apply` and has a signature

```
def ap[A, B](ff: F[A => B])(fa: F[A]): F[B]
```

So `map` applies a **function** `A => B` to a value in a context `F[A]` while `ap` applies a **function** `F[A => B]` **in a context** to a value in a context `F[A]`.

For example

```
Apply[List].map(List(1, 2))(intToString)
```

is `List("1", "2")` while

```
Apply[List].ap(List(intToString, (i: Int) => intToString(i) + "a"))(List(1, 2))
```

is `List("1", "2", "1a", "2a")`.

`Apply[Option].map(fx)(f)` can be `None` only when `fx` is `None` while `Apply[Option].ap(ff)(fx)` can be `None` when `fx` is `None` or `ff` is `None`.